# Using bindkey to call a function in zsh requires pressing enter after function runs

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm new to zsh and am trying to bind a key sequence to a function with the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
say_hello(){
    echo "hello"
}
zle -N say_hello
bindkey '^Y' say_hello
```

Pressing Ctrl-Y will call the function and I'll see "hello" printed to the terminal but after I need to press Enter again before I'm given another zsh prompt. Calling the function by just typing in `say_hello` at the zsh prompt and pressing Enter does what I want - I see hello printed and then I'm given another zsh prompt. How can I get this behavior when binding the function to a key sequence?

Above is a simple example, really the function I'm trying to write is below:

```
my_cd() {
    if [[ "$#" -ne 0 ]]; then
        cd $(autojump $@)
        return
    fi
    dir_to_cd_to=$(fasd_cd -dl |  fzf --height 40% --reverse --inline-info)
    # above isn't so important - dir_to_cd_to could be obtained in any way
    cd "$dir_to_cd_to"
}

zle -N my_cd
bindkey -v '^Y' 'my_cd'
```

Comment: Is your intention to run a command on `^Y` or just to insert text in your commandline?

Comment: @MartinTournoij no the function I really want to run involves changing the current directory, I'm just using the `echo` command in the example here to illustrate the behavior I don't understand.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `zsh` is already waiting for your input; you don't *need* to hit Enter (causing the prompt to be redisplayed) before typing your next command. The output simply wrote "hello" and a newline to the terminal in the same place where your input would have been echoed by the terminal.

Comment: You might be interested in `print -z` instead, which will write directly to the input buffer as if you had typed text instead. That might be an alternative to having `zle` call a function "out of band", so to speak.

Comment: @chepner thanks. So I added an example of what I really want - a function that changes the working directory, that is run with a keybinding. Can you recommend how to make this work so that I will be given my zsh prompt after the function finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display messages in a zle widget, you're supposed to use `zle -M` rather than `echo`. `echo` will output your message at whatever the current cursor position is which isn't especially helpful. If you really want to use echo, calling `zle reset-prompt` afterwards will redraw a fresh prompt. If you don't want a potential mess in your terminal, consider starting with `\r` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line and ending with `$termcap[ce]` to clear to the end of the line.

Comment: good to know, but I'm just using `echo` here to show the behavior I don't understand - what I really want to do in the function is more than just printing something

Comment: woops missed the `zle reset-prompt` part of this answer - that was the key part that did what I was looking for